# Problems with a custom loss function in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I need to have a custom Keras loss function. 
The following code works with loss function *loss2* but not using loss function *loss1*. I am getting errors as

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.

I have decorated the function with @tf.function but it does not work.

```
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LeakyReLU

def individual_model(keys, labels):
    model = Sequential()
    size = 32
    model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=1))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    for i in range(2):
        model.add(Dense(size))
        model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=my_loss, metrics=[
                my_loss])
    model.fit(keys, labels, epochs=256, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
    return model


def loss1(v):
    if v<0:
        return -100 * v
    else: 
        return v

def loss2(v):
    return v*v

def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.map_fn(loss1,y_true-y_pred) #with loss2 this works


x=np.random.exponential(100,1000)
x.sort()
labels=np.arange(0,1000)
m=individual_model(x,labels)
```

Comment: You could try using [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) in place of your if/else statement. Can't test right now so not sure.

Comment: @Engineero Thank you for the hint. But can you clarify on why?

Comment: Things change pretty rapidly with TF, so I may be wrong, but I think there's no way for TF to recognize Python if/else statements as graph operations and represent them in a graph, so there's no way for TF to execute those statements at execution time. They work if your network *configuration* is dependent on some condition at startup, but once that configuration is set, Python is out of the picture and it's all native TF running. So if you want to use a condition, it has to be one that TF can represent in the graph, and that's stuff like `tf.cond` or `tf.where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tf.where** could be used in loss v1 definition something like this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where):

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 
arr = np.array([1., -1])
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(tf.where(arr<0., arr*100., arr*10.))
```

Output:

```
array([  10., -100.])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Engineero recommendation.

The following code works

```
def cond_switch(x):
    return K.relu(-x)*10 + K.relu(x)

def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return cond_switch(y_true-y_pred)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `figure out the reason`? Do you want to implement `v1` efficiently and are unsure why `cond_switch` returns what `v1` should or are you just testing `tensorflow`, conditionals etc.?

Comment: re @SzymonMaszke, figure out the reason why my original code was not working.